# Single page addition to 'singlepage' website not working

Tags: hugo

I might be asking a stupid question but I've spent days on stackoverflow and git as well as Hugo's official documentation and I've gotten 15 different ways of doing something and nothing seems to work.

I have a 1 page hugo website and I want to add in a privacy policy.

Within the `root/config.toml` I have the following:
`[[params.footer.quicklinks]]`
`text = "Privacy Policy"`
`link = "privacypolicy.html"`

Within `root/content` I have a file called `privacypolicy.md` with the following:
`---`
`title: "Privacy Policy"`
`type: page`
`page: "privacypolicy.html"`
`---`

Within `root/layout/page` I have `privacypolicy.html`

When I click the link on the core page to go to the privacy policy I get a '404 page not found'

Comment: Are you running hugo server? Does it notice the new content in your root/content folder? Does it render it?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: what version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the typo `layouts`. Put the `privacypolicy.html` file in `root/layouts/page` dir.
Create a new `page` dir and put the `privacypolicy.md` in `root/content/page`. 
Use Url tag in md file like this:

```
---
  title: "your title"
  type: page
  Url: page/privacypolicy
---
Your content here...
```

This will open in your http://baseUrl/page/privacypolicy. Recommended to rerun `hugo server` and hard refresh(ctrl shift R) web pages.